# How to explicitly search for plural words

Tags: support, search, plurals

In JSF there exist tags with singular and plural names like `<h:message>`/`<h:messages>` and `<p:column>`/`<p:columns>`.

When attempting to search for my posts about `<p:columns>` using the keywords [user:157882 p:columns](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20p:columns), I got results including `<p:column>`, making it harder to find the specific posts.

I understand the reasoning very good and I actually like it, but this just doesn't work in this particular search. How can I explicitly search for the pluralized form?

Additionally, I tried to search for `<p:columns>` in code like so [user:157882 code:"p:columns"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20code:%22p:columns%22), but that didn't give any results.

Comment: Drat, I should have experimented a bit more, [user:157882 "<p:columns>"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A157882+%22%3Cp%3Acolumns%3E%22) works.

Comment: Might be overkill, but it might be easier to do a query on the http://data.stackexchange.com/ specifying for what you want to match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's always wrapped in code, the current search is: [`user:157882 "<p:columns>"`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:157882%20%22%3Cp:columns%3E%22)

I'll be working on the punctuation-at-the-ends problem as soon as time allows, still moving infrastructure around at the moment. I want `"p:columns"` to work, it *should* work, we just have a parsing trade-off problem right now.

Comment: Yes, I figured it 3 seconds before your answer. Thank you nevertheless :)